# google maps map under materialize tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I tried to create a site that looks fast by changing the content dynamically, so I use the tab system form materialize, everything works great, except that my google maps map that is generate via the api shows as a blank window:
[map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N8yr.png)

it shows the map when I resize my window or if the page is active, active isn't a solution!

Thanks in advance for possible solutions/fixes

I created this JSFiddle to showcase it: https://jsfiddle.net/8ajob4ja/

**html:**

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col s12">
       <ul class="tabs">
         <li class="tab col s6"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
         <li class="tab col s6"><a href="#test2" class="active">Test 2</a></li>
</ul>
      </div>
      <div id="test1" class="col s12">           
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
    </script>
      </div>
      <div id="test2" class="col s12">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
```

**js:**

```
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });
}
```

**css:**

```
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code. Because google is directly calling `initMap()` when script is execute so at that time due to some reason map object is not initialised So for that reason we need to call `initMap()` like this way.

Remove **&callback=initMap** from js link so it will look like as below.

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
</script>
```

Add class in tab.

```
<li class="tab col s6 test"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
```

Replace your jquery with this code.

```
$(".test").click(function () {initMap();});

function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger the `resize` event on the map after the tab becomes active (and the map has a size).

```
$('ul.tabs').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  }, 500);
});
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });
}
$('ul.tabs').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab col s6"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s6"><a href="#test2" class="active">Test 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="test1" class="col s12">

    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </div>

  <div id="test2" class="col s12">
    2
  </div>

</div>
```